# Why doesn't the text/block display when I hover over the image?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't the text/block display when I hover over the image? I have the html/css provided below. I really dont't know why it doesn't display when I hover over the image. (I'm just trying to hover over the first image out of the four displayed)

This is the particular relevant css snippet that I tried to use to hover over the image and display text:

```
 /* HOVER STYLES */
    div#pop-up1, #pop-up2, #pop-up3, #pop-up4 {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        width: 280px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        color: #000000;
        border: 3px solid #196CE8; /*#f7923a;*/
        font-size: 90%;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    trigger1:hover #pop-up1 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
      }
```

This is the particular html snippet:

```
          <section id="promo_area">
        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger1"><img alt="paris" src="Paris.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
            </div>

            <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
            <div id="pop-up1">
                <h3>Paris</h3>
                <p>MUN in Paris 2013.</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger2"><img alt="Russia" src="russia.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
            </div>

            <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
            <div id="pop-up2">
                <h3>Russia</h3>
                <p>MUN in Russia 2014</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger3"><img alt="Dubai" src="dubai.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
            </div>

            <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
            <div id="pop-up3">
                <h3>Dubai</h3>
                <p>MUN in Dubai 2015</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger4"><img alt="Japan" src="japan.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
            </div>

            <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
            <div id="pop-up4">
                <h3>Japan</h3>
                <p>MUN in Japan 2016</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section><!--end promo_area-->
```

This is the full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Birdwatching</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
      <style>
html
{ height: 100%;
          }

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: normal .80em 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #F0EFE2 url(ff.jpg) repeat;
  color: #000;
  width: 97%;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin:0 auto;
          }

p
{ padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;}

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7E2451;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 175% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font: normal 120% arial, sans-serif;}

h5, h6
{ font: italic 95% arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;}

nav ul {
    background: url(transparent.png) ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
       }

nav ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

nav ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font: normal 100% arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 9px 26px 9px 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    } 

nav ul li a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #fff;
    } 

.dropdown {
   display:inline-block;
   position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black; 
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align:left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background: #bada55;
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
 main
{ width: 854px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 24px 20px 20px;
  background: transparent url(transparent_light.png) repeat;} 

 #first_half article
{ text-align: left;
  float: left;
 width: 595px;
    /width:60%;
    height: 50pc;

  padding: 0;}

#first_half article ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 0px;}

#first_half article ul li
{ list-style-type: none;
  background: url(bullet.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 25px;
  line-height: 1.5em;} 

#first_half aside
{ float: right;
  width: 210px;
    /width: 25%;
  /padding: 0 15px 20px 15px;
    padding: 0;
  height: 50pc;
          }

#first_half aside ul
{ width: 198px; 
  padding: 4px 0 0 0; 
  margin: 4px 0 30px 0;}

#first_half aside li
{ list-style: none; 
  padding: 0 0 7px 0; }

#first_half aside li a, #first_half .sidebar li a:hover
{ padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(link.png) no-repeat left center;} 

#first_half aside li a.selected
{ color: #7E2451;
  text-decoration: none;} 

#promo_area  article {

            float:left;
    width: 25%;
      /height: 50pc;
            padding:10px 0;
            border-top:  solid #f7be84;
            /background:#fff; 
            text-align: center;

        }
        #promo_area article .inner {
            margin:0 10px;
            padding:10px;
            background:#e5e8ed;
            /border-radius: 25px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
            text-align: center;
        } 
        #promo_area article p {
            font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';
            font-weight:300;
            font-size:1em;
            line-height:1.5em;
            color:#616161;
        }
        /* HOVER STYLES */
        div#pop-up1, #pop-up2, #pop-up3, #pop-up4 {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            color: #000000;
            border: 3px solid #196CE8; /*#f7923a;*/
            font-size: 90%;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        trigger1:hover #pop-up1 {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
          }

      </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Model United Nations Deforestation Conference</h1>
      <img src="dove.png" alt="a simple dove logo">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Get started</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Preparation</a>
                    <a href="#">D-Day</a>
                    <a href="#">Useful Resources</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">MUN 2015</a>
                    <a href="#">MUN 2016</a>
                    <a href="#">MUN 2017</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Ask A Question</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact Information</a>
                    <a href="#">Map</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Forum</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Sign-Up</a>
                    <a href="#">Community</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </nav> 
    </header>

      <main>
        <section id = "first_half">
      <article>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>

        <p>Welcome to our fake birdwatching site. If this were a real site, it would be the ideal place to come to learn more about birdwatching, whether you are a beginner looking to learn how to get into birding, or an expert wanting to share ideas, tips, and photos with other like-minded people.</p>

        <p>So don't waste time! Get what you need, then turn off that computer and get out into the great outdoors!</p>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ojcNcvb1olg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen sandbox></iframe>
        <h2>Rocking the free web</h2>

        <p>Mozilla are a global community of technologists, thinkers, and builders, working together to keep the Internet alive and accessible, so people worldwide can be informed contributors and creators of the Web. We believe this act of human collaboration across an open platform is essential to individual growth and our collective future.</p>

        <p>Click on the images below to find more information about the cool stuff Mozilla does. <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/mathiasappel/21675551065/">Red panda picture</a> by Mathias Appel.</p>
      </article>

                 <aside>
                  <form>
<h1>Payment form</h1>
          <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
    <section>
    <h2>Contact information</h2>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Title</legend>
      <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="title_1">
              <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="M." >
              Mister
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="title_2">
              <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="Ms.">
              Miss
            </label>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="name">
        <span>Name: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="mail">
        <span>E-mail: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="email" id="mail" name="usermail">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="pwd">
        <span>Password: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password">
    </p>
</section>
          <section>
    <h2>Payment information</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="card">
        <span>Card type:</span>
      </label>
      <select id="card" name="usercard">
        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="mc">Mastercard</option>
        <option value="amex">American Express</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="number">
        <span>Card number:</span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="cardnumber">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="date">
        <span>Expiration date:</span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
        <em>formatted as mm/yy</em>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="date" name="expiration">
    </p>
</section>
 <p> <button type="submit">Validate the payment</button> </p>

</form>
        </aside>
          </section>
          <section id="promo_area">
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger1"><img alt="paris" src="Paris.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up1">
                    <h3>Paris</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Paris 2013.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger2"><img alt="Russia" src="russia.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up2">
                    <h3>Russia</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Russia 2014</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger3"><img alt="Dubai" src="dubai.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up3">
                    <h3>Dubai</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Dubai 2015</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger4"><img alt="Japan" src="japan.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up4">
                    <h3>Japan</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Japan 2016</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section><!--end promo_area-->
      </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `trigger1:hover #pop-up1` won't apply to anything since there is no `<trigger>` element containing a nested child element with the `id` `#pop-up1`. The `pseudo-state` `:hover` will only apply to nested elements, so in order for your rule to work you would need to move `#pop-up1` into `#trigger1`, then `#trigger1:hover #pop-up1` will apply

Answer (score 0):

First of all the css code you used to display it is not correct   `trigger1:hover #pop-up1` , as per you requirement i placed a simple css at the bottom , where `+` is used for the Adjacent sibling combinator

```
 #promo_area article .inner:hover + div {
 display: block;
 visibility: visible;
 }
```

```css
html
{ height: 100%;
          }

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

body
{ font: normal .80em 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #F0EFE2 url(ff.jpg) repeat;
  color: #000;
  width: 97%;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin:0 auto;
          }

p
{ padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;}

img
{ border: 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{ font: normal 175% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7E2451;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;}

h2
{ font: normal 175% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;}

h4, h5, h6
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font: normal 120% arial, sans-serif;}

h5, h6
{ font: italic 95% arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;}

nav ul {
    background: url(transparent.png) ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
       }

nav ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

nav ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font: normal 100% arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 9px 26px 9px 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    } 

nav ul li a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #fff;
    } 

.dropdown {
   display:inline-block;
   position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black; 
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align:left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background: #bada55;
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    margin-right:-10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
 main
{ width: 854px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 24px 20px 20px;
  background: transparent url(transparent_light.png) repeat;} 

 #first_half article
{ text-align: left;
  float: left;
 width: 595px;
    /width:60%;
    height: 50pc;

  padding: 0;}

#first_half article ul
{ margin: 2px 0 22px 0px;}

#first_half article ul li
{ list-style-type: none;
  background: url(bullet.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 25px;
  line-height: 1.5em;} 

#first_half aside
{ float: right;
  width: 210px;
    /width: 25%;
  /padding: 0 15px 20px 15px;
    padding: 0;
  height: 50pc;
          }

#first_half aside ul
{ width: 198px; 
  padding: 4px 0 0 0; 
  margin: 4px 0 30px 0;}

#first_half aside li
{ list-style: none; 
  padding: 0 0 7px 0; }

#first_half aside li a, #first_half .sidebar li a:hover
{ padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(link.png) no-repeat left center;} 

#first_half aside li a.selected
{ color: #7E2451;
  text-decoration: none;} 

#promo_area  article {

            float:left;
    width: 25%;
      /height: 50pc;
            padding:10px 0;
            border-top:  solid #f7be84;
            /background:#fff; 
            text-align: center;

        }
        #promo_area article .inner {
            margin:0 10px;
            padding:10px;
            background:#e5e8ed;
            /border-radius: 25px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
            text-align: center;
        } 
        #promo_area article p {
            font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';
            font-weight:300;
            font-size:1em;
            line-height:1.5em;
            color:#616161;
        }
        /* HOVER STYLES */
        div#pop-up1, #pop-up2, #pop-up3, #pop-up4 {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            color: #000000;
            border: 3px solid #196CE8; /*#f7923a;*/
            font-size: 90%;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        trigger1:hover #pop-up1 {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
            }
            
    #promo_area article .inner:hover + div {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>Model United Nations Deforestation Conference</h1>
      <img src="dove.png" alt="a simple dove logo">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Get started</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Preparation</a>
                    <a href="#">D-Day</a>
                    <a href="#">Useful Resources</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">MUN 2015</a>
                    <a href="#">MUN 2016</a>
                    <a href="#">MUN 2017</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Ask A Question</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact Information</a>
                    <a href="#">Map</a>
                </div>
            </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Forum</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Sign-Up</a>
                    <a href="#">Community</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </nav> 
    </header>

      <main>
        <section id = "first_half">
      <article>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>

        <p>Welcome to our fake birdwatching site. If this were a real site, it would be the ideal place to come to learn more about birdwatching, whether you are a beginner looking to learn how to get into birding, or an expert wanting to share ideas, tips, and photos with other like-minded people.</p>

        <p>So don't waste time! Get what you need, then turn off that computer and get out into the great outdoors!</p>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ojcNcvb1olg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen sandbox></iframe>
        <h2>Rocking the free web</h2>

        <p>Mozilla are a global community of technologists, thinkers, and builders, working together to keep the Internet alive and accessible, so people worldwide can be informed contributors and creators of the Web. We believe this act of human collaboration across an open platform is essential to individual growth and our collective future.</p>

        <p>Click on the images below to find more information about the cool stuff Mozilla does. <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/mathiasappel/21675551065/">Red panda picture</a> by Mathias Appel.</p>
      </article>

                 <aside>
                  <form>
<h1>Payment form</h1>
          <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
    <section>
    <h2>Contact information</h2>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Title</legend>
      <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="title_1">
              <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="M." >
              Mister
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="title_2">
              <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="Ms.">
              Miss
            </label>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="name">
        <span>Name: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="mail">
        <span>E-mail: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="email" id="mail" name="usermail">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="pwd">
        <span>Password: </span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password">
    </p>
</section>
          <section>
    <h2>Payment information</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="card">
        <span>Card type:</span>
      </label>
      <select id="card" name="usercard">
        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="mc">Mastercard</option>
        <option value="amex">American Express</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="number">
        <span>Card number:</span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
      </label>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="cardnumber">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="date">
        <span>Expiration date:</span>
        <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
        <em>formatted as mm/yy</em>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="date" name="expiration">
    </p>
</section>
 <p> <button type="submit">Validate the payment</button> </p>

</form>
        </aside>
          </section>
          <section id="promo_area">
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger1"><img alt="paris" src="Paris.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up1">
                    <h3>Paris</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Paris 2013.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger2"><img alt="Russia" src="russia.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up2">
                    <h3>Russia</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Russia 2014</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger3"><img alt="Dubai" src="dubai.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up3">
                    <h3>Dubai</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Dubai 2015</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="picDiv"><span id="trigger4"><img alt="Japan" src="japan.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span></div>
                </div>

                <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
                <div id="pop-up4">
                    <h3>Japan</h3>
                    <p>MUN in Japan 2016</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section><!--end promo_area-->
      </main>
```